# How to copy 100 words from memory?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm learning MIPS as a hobby and use the QtSPIM simulator. This is my first ever program

My question from the book:

> 1. Write a program that copies 100 words from location `'SRC'` in memory, to another location named `'DEST'` in memory.

Btw, I know it may be wrong to run the loop 100 times. I haven't calculated that part yet.

I would just like to know if my program copies the bits from `src` and puts them in dest.

Does it at least accomplish this?

Please don't reveal the complete solution, just give me some tips, etc.

Here is my attempt (MY FIRST TIME PROGRAMMING!):

```
.data
src:  .space 400
dest: .space 400

.text
main:

la $t6, src     # t6 = pointer for src
la $t7, dest    # t7 = pointer for dest
li $t0, 100     # t0 = initialise countdown

loop:

lw $t1, ($t6)      # load 32 bits from src

sw $t2, ($t7)      # store bits from src to dest

addi $t6, $t6, 4   # add 4 to pointer to get next 32 bits of src 

addi $t7, $t7, 4   # add 4 to pointer to get next 32 bits of dest

addi $t0, $t0, -1      # countdown minus 1

bgt $t0, $zero, loop   # loop if countdown > 0

jr $ra    # end
```

Comment: Your first time programming, ever, is on a MIPS simulator running on an iPad using assembly?

Comment: The program looks correct except for an off-by-one error. But if I understand the question, you can't tell if it's working properly or not. You need to set up the simulator so as to tell whether your programs are working, or there's no point writing them. And this is not a real question.

Comment: If the intention is to copy data, I'm not sure why you load the data into one register, and then store a different (uninitialised) one.

Answer (score 0):

Your program simply loads a value from `SRC` to `$t1` and then store some random value from `$t2` to `DEST`, so it needs some changes. Did you tried any debugging before?

```
lw $t1, ($t6)      # load 32 bits from src
sw $t2, ($t7)      # store bits from src to dest
```

And no need to loop for 100 times. You can do some loop unrolling